# Android app crashing with permissions issues when binding to service

Tags: java, android, permissions, intentfilter, bindservice

I'm trying to extend the binder class to call a method in my service but can't get the intents to match the intent filters. There are two scenarios.

1. If I setup my intent as below, bindService returns true, startService returns Component Info and the service starts but the app immediately crashes:

   ```
   private LocationUpdateService mService;
   Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
   updateServiceIntent = new Intent(activity, LocationUpdateService.class);

   Boolean successful = activity.bindService(updateServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   ComponentName serviceStarted = activity.startService(updateServiceIntent);
   ```
2. If I setup my intent as below, bindService returns false, the service doesn't start, and the app doesn't crash.

   ```
   private LocationUpdateService mService;
   Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
   updateServiceIntent = new Intent("com.tentforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.LocationUpdateService");

   Boolean successful = activity.bindService(updateServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
   ComponentName serviceStarted = activity.startService(updateServiceIntent);
   ```

Either way, logcat displays the following error:

```
ContextImpl(  704): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1510 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.sendNotification:981 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.removeNotification:706 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotificationLocked:2455 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.access$5100:160
```

My androidManifest.xml has the following intent-filters setup. I tried to catch both of my intent setups:

```
<activity android:name="com.tentforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.BackgroundGpsPlugin">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.tentforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.LocationUpdateService" />
        <action android:name="LocationUpdateService" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.tenforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.LocationUpdateService" android:process=":remote" />
```

Please let me know any troubleshooting ideas you may have. I've been playing with combinations of intent and intent-filters for a while now. I really appreciate any help!

Comment: "but the app immediately crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this "If I setup my intent as below, bindService returns false, the service doesn't start, and the app doesn't crash" -- that is because it does not match your service. Your service does not have an `<intent-filter>`. "Either way, logcat displays the following error" -- that is not coming from your app.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have been using LogCat. I saw another error in there: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to com.tenforwardconsulting.cordova.bgloc.LocationUpdateService$LocalBinder`. I think this is because my service is specified to run in a remote process so I can't just extend the binder class. I think I will have to use a Messenger or AIDL. Sad day! Thanks for the help.